# iOS 6 Using Google Maps without UIWebView

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, ios6, ios6-maps

Is there any native solution using **Google maps** in **iOS6** development? 
Let's not assume `UIWebView`.

What do you think, are developers going to use Apple maps because they don't want to use `UIWebView`?

Comment: I think developers will still use MKMapView

Comment: @phix23 You mean no way no choice?...

Comment: My app uses MKMapView currently but users are starting to complain about lose of satellite imagery in many areas (or maximum zoom is still too far out to use). So I'm contemplating switching over to a UIWebView with Google Maps API3 for Javascript. I just have to figure out how to handle rotation properly (rotating map based on direction user is facing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under iOS 6.0 you will have to use UIWebView (the google maps rendering 'engine' is not present as before), this might change in the future but it's not very likely because google and apple don't like each other any longer.

Comment: Update: Now you can use the google Maps SDK for iOS -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Answer (score 1):

How about using layered map tiles on top of Mapkit? [See this link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_in_MapKit)

Comment: That is not permitted by Google's ToS. Here is the answer from [@GoogleMapsAPI on Twitter.](https://twitter.com/GoogleMapsAPI/status/253551273796841472)